# Handler data IO throughput?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

What is the feasible data IO throughput of android `Handlers`?  Enough to pass raw audio or video between threads?  Should it be sustainable?

I've not seen any reference to this in the [android `Handler` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), $WEB_SEARCH, or SO per this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Enough to pass raw audio or video between threads? Should it be
>   sustainable?

It depends on your implementation. Eventually, you either want shared-memory based or deep copy based communication. If you want to send a copy of data (or a continuous stream of data chunk copies), it will have a performance overhead, but not due to `Handlers`, but because of the actual memory copying.

This is because `Handlers` merely send & handle `Message` objects. You can use the `obj` field of the `Message` to pass any object reference, i.e. you can use it to send a (synchronized) reference to any data. If you send the original reference to some data, it will be like shared memory communication. If you make a copy of the data first, and send the reference to that copy, it's basically deep copying. In either case, you're working on the same process memory area, so the sustainibility depends on the communication protocol and not on `Handlers`. (Obviously, if you send a `Message` for each `int` value of the audio/video data, it will be very slow.)